# How to shutdown and then reboot linux machine using python Language or shell script?

Tags: python-2.7

Am trying to shutdown and boot it again the Linux system using python language or shell script. can anyone clarify me in this ? even crontab is also okay

Answer (score 17):

shell

```
reboot
```

python

```
import os
os.system('reboot')
```

Note: You need root permission to do reboot operation.

You should take some time to learn `Linux basic concepts` first.

Answer (score 6):

If you don't want to give root privileges to the python process, you can use `systemctl reboot -i`.

```
import os
os.system('systemctl reboot -i')
```

However, this will ignore all inhibitors, including other users logged in, etc. Use with caution.

Comment: Note that you need to install the `systemd` package in order to use this command. Install with `sudo apt-get install systemd`

Answer (score 5):

You need two things to make your linux system to reboot.

1 - Give the user executing your script the privilege for reboot

`$ sudo visudo -f /etc/sudoers.d/reboot_privilege`

add line :

`<user> ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: /sbin/reboot`

2 - Execute the python code :

```
import os
os.system("sudo reboot")
```

It will reboot your system without any prompt nor check password.

Comment: Hi, how i remove this "reboot_privilage" file from my system. when i write the "sudo" on the terminal the following error occurs. "no valid sudoers sources found, quitting"